# how can i use scrapy's Itemloader in my amazon spider so that i can remove all the new line chars or extra white spaces from the output

Tags: python, scrapy

i am trying to scrape amazon using scrapy, everything works fine except for the author field
for which i am getting an output like,

```
{'author': ['Somasundaram Chenrayan',
            'B. Latha B. லதா',
            'Mugil முகில்',
            'ஜே. சி. குமரப்பா',
            ' and ',
            'மீ. விநாயகம்',
            '\n'
            '    \n'
            '        \n'
            '        \n'
            '            Napoleon Hill\n'
            '        \n'
            '    \n',
            '\n'
            '    \n'
            '        \n'
            '        \n'
            '            Joseph Murphy\n'
            '        \n'
            '    \n',
            'டாக்டர் அம்பேத்கர்',
            'MALINI SUNDAR',
            '\n'
            '    \n'
            '        \n'
            '        \n'
            '            வாணி அரவிந்த்\n'
            '        \n'
            '    \n',
            'sankareswari சங்கரேஸ்வரி',
            '\n'
            '    \n'
            '        \n'
            '        \n'
            '            George S Clason\n'
            '        \n'
            '    \n',
            'சசிகுமார்  தங்கவேல் ',
            'ஆர். ஷண்முகசுந்தரம்',]
```

after checking some answers on stackexchange, i have written the below mentioned code in my items module so that i can remove all the extra spaces from the author field but it's not really working

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.loader.processors import MapCompose
from w3lib.html import remove_tags

def normalize_space(value):
    return " ".join(value.split())

class Product(scrapy.Item):
    author = scrapy.Field(
        input_processor=MapCompose(remove_tags, normalize_space),
    )
    book_name = scrapy.Field()
    price = scrapy.Field()
    image_links = scrapy.Field()
```

And here's my spider's code:

```
import scrapy
from ..items import Product

class AmazonSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    # page_number = 1

    name = "amazon"
    start_urls = [
        "https://www.amazon.in/s?bbn=976389031&rh=n%3A976389031%2Cp_n_publication_date%3A2684819031&dc&fst=as%3Aoff&qid=1588845227&rnid=2684818031&ref=lp_976389031_nr_p_n_publication_date_0"
    ]

    def parse(self, response):

        items = Product()

        book_name = response.css(".a-color-base.a-text-normal").css("::text").extract()
        price = response.css(".a-price span::text").extract()
        author = response.css(".a-color-secondary .a-size-base+ .a-size-base").css("::text").extract()
        image_links = response.css("div img::attr(src)").extract()

        items["book_name"] = book_name
        items["price"] = price
        items["author"] = author
        items["image_links"] = image_links
        yield items
```

scince i'm new to scrapy I don't know how to solve this problem. I will really appriciate if u could tell me what's wrong with this code or how can i solve this using re, I also tried with re but it's only giving syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be mixing [items](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/items.html) and [item loaders](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html). You are not using item loaders, so defining `input_processor` is useless.

Have a closer look at the second code snipet of the [documentation](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html#declaring-input-and-output-processors), where an item loader (as opposed to an item) is used to extract the data and apply the defined input processor.